# Pass arbitrary SVG icon to Pug mixin without "block"

Tags: pug

### Targets

1. Message box must be the component with icon and arbitrary content, like paragraphs, lists, etc. The reason of 'without "block"' in the title of this question is `block` is being already used inside `.AttentionBox-MainSection`.
2. There is the default SVG icon in component, however it must could be substituted with arbitrary custom SVG icon.

```
mixin AttentionBox(propertiesObject)
 
  - const {
    customIcon
  } = propertiesObject

  .AttentionBox

    if !customIcon
      svg.AttentionBox-Icon(viewBox="0 0 24 24")
        path(d="M5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3M13,13V7H11V13H13M13,17V15H11V17H13Z")
      else 
        //- ???
    
      .AttentionBox-MainSection
        block //- arbitrary content
```

### Difficulties

I learned that basically no way to store pug mixin execution result to variable.
There is [only hacky way](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/3235#issuecomment-616307402) to do it, but it looks like make a big impact to performance (even for pre-processing before deploying), non-intuitive and make the code hard to read. Too expensive price.

There is a [way to emulate the slots](https://codepen.io/monochromer/pen/prqRRK) in Pug. However, it have the tangible limitations:

1. Nested mixin-components with slots are not supported because `slots` variable will be overridden. E. g. if we want to use the `AttentionBox` inside modal from the link - maybe there will not be a pug compilation error, however there will not the the expected output too.
2. The `slots` could be used only after `block`.

### Unsatisfying solutions

1. Pass svg's path's attribute `d` value as mixin parameter: works for single-path svg icons, but svg tag content is unknown in advance (could be multiple paths, circles etc.)
2. Pass icon html code as mixin parameter: we should to avoid to write the HTML in Pug, but also the icon could the another pug mixin.
3. Using switch/case like this:

```
case:
  when Icons.info
    +Icon-Info
  when Icons.warning
    +Icon-Info
```

The custom icon is arbitrary, in could be not among `Icons`.

### Other example

In below `DropdownSelect` component, `block` is being used for option list.
What if user wants to use custom SVG icon?

```
mixin DropdownSelect(parametersObject)
    
  -
    const {
      currentSelectionText,
      nothingSelectedText = "select please ...",
      customIcon
    } = parametersObject

  .DropdownSelect
    div.DropdownSelect-CurrentSelectionView(
      role="button"
      aria-haspopup="listbox"
    )= currentSelectionText || nothingSelectedText
      if !customIcon
          svg.DropdownSelect-Icon(
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          ): path(d="M7.41,8.58L12,13.17L16.59,8.58L18,10L12,16L6,10L7.41,8.58Z")
        else 
            // ??
      if block
        .DropdownSelect-OptionsList(
          role="list"
          aria-expanded="true"
          tabindex="-1"
        )
          block
```

Comment: Does the SVG icon have to be rendered as an inline SVG? Is it possible to instead reference the SVG as the `src` of an `<img>` element? If it must be inline, would it be possible to define it beforehand and then pass its `id` to a `<use>` element as a parameter?

Comment: @Sean, thank you for the comment. "Does the SVG icon have to be rendered as an inline SVG?" - Yes. "Is it possible to instead reference the SVG as the src of an <img> element?" - undesirably, because it's will become more requests to server. "If it must be inline, would it be possible to define it beforehand and then pass its id to a <use> element as a parameter?" - I did not know about "use"... I think it's could be a solution. Would you please to post a simple example in answer?

Comment: @Sean, I suppose, to inject multiple elements via `use`, some SVG wrapper will requires same as Vue and Reach components required common container. Is some SVG element witch just wrapping other element but does not affect to child elements?